# Long open database session

Tags: oracle, spring-data, websphere

We are using the websphere as application server and spring-data to access an oracle database.
If we call the start page on our application, different data and a lot of labels from **three different frames** are loaded parallely from the database.
Now, if we monitor the database while open the start page, different database sessions are opened and closed. However, **three sessions** (get labels) are kept open, but inactive.
I think **three** sessions, because I have three frames and they all load a lot of labels parallely.

Is there a functionality in websphere, spring-data or oracle that recognizes when a sql statement is often executed and keeps the session open?

Or do you know why the sessions is kept open?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server data sources support pooling of connections and caching of prepared statements.  This is enabled by default.  As long as your application is using the WebSphere Application Server data source (obtained via resource injection @Resource or JNDI lookup) and uses java.sql.PreparedStatement for your SQL commands, PreparedStatements will be kept in the cache and reused as needed.  It isn't clear from your question if you want this behavior or if you want to avoid it.  If you are looking to disable caching of all prepared statements, you can configure the statementCacheSize of the data source to 0.  Alternately, if there are only specific prepared statements that you wish to avoid caching, you can programmatically set the JDBC poolability hint on them:

```
preparedStatement.setPoolable(false);
```

Comment: Why is a database session open, if the value is chached? Different labels are loaded each time and not always the same.

Comment: The prepared statement caching done by WebSphere Application Server only involves caching the java.sql.PreparedStatement, not the value returned by SQL queries or the values of parameters.

Comment: We are using getJdbcTemplate().call(...) to connect to the database. Is this using also the caching? I will not disable this cache. I only want to know why this session kept open.